# how to set background as transparent in Box Decoartion?

Tags: flutter, dart

setting bg color to transparent is giving me a white bg in a button , what am i doing wrong how can i set it to transparent ?
**here is my code :**

```
                      child: InkWell(
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                        ),
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .065,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
```

Comment: if the background is white, then transparent will make your button white as well. If you want it to be slightly transparent you can use ```color: Color(0x220000ff)``` with 22 being the opacity and ff the blue color. (read about ARGB).

Comment: Why do you need to pass the color? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL the background is gradient color but the button gets white when i set it to transparent

Comment: @AfridiKayal the color of the button is blue at the moment but i want to have the transparent background in the button